# Optimized assembly code (BLAS)

Tags: optimization, assembly, blas

So, usually the answer to questions about improving performance via assembly code is along the lines of "don't bother, compilers are smarter than you".  And I get that.

But, I've noticed that optimized linear algebra libraries (eg ACML) can achieve performance improvements in the range of 2x to 5x over standard compiled libraries.  For example, on my 8-core machine, I've had optimized matrix multiplication run over 30x faster versus the stock single-threaded BLAS implementation, meaning that, after accounting for the 8x improvement due to using all the cores, there's still a 4x improvement simply from optimization.

So it looks to me like optimized assembly code really can make a huge difference.  Am I missing something?

I'm asking, because if it's not outlandishly difficult, I might be inclined to try this on some other segments of code.  Nothing complicated, but if I can get a 2x improvement on some small inner loop by writing it in assembly, it might be worth it.

Comment: What's the question?  Certainly for specific problems, hand-tuning the code at that level can result in real gains.

Comment: @Carl I guess the question is, what do these BLAS implementations do to get such a performance improvement, and how widely applicable are those techniques.

Comment: The old rule of thumb was that 10% of your code accounts for 90% of runtime, so having a very close look at that 10% of the code with a profiler and analyzing the compiler-generated assembly code will almost certainly help you find spots that can be sped up at lot by a manual rewrite in assembler.  But use this technique sparingly, in small increments (first the most promising candidates, followed by new benchmarking) and only if the speed gain is high enough, because this technique can seriously affect the maintainability of your code.

Comment: How many seconds does it take to multiply two square matrices of 8192x8192 ?

Answer (score 4):

The speedup of the matrix-matrix product is only partially due to using assembly code.  In a naive implementation the main bottleneck is memory access.  Most of the time your CPU will wait for doing actual computations.

You first have to modify the algorithm for the matrix-matrix multiplication such that data in the L2 and L1 caches can be reused as often as possible.  This can be done in C (or C++ or Fortran or ...).  This will lead to an implementation that does not break down when matrix sizes become bigger than your cache.  And it also means that the implementation can do computations all the time (data which is needed in CPU registers is almost always in L1 Cache, Data needed in L1 cache is almost always in L2 cache, ...).

The next step is optimizing the hot spot where all the computations are done.  This involves only a few lines of the C Code (in my [GEMM Tutorial](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/sghpc/gemm) only 10 lines).  The assembly code does optimizations with respect to instructions pipelining, loop unrolling (for improving branch prediction), prefetching (for reducing cache misses), using SSE (or AVX).

Similar techniques can be used for other BLAS Level 3 functions.  Actually most of them use the internal stuff (the so called micro kernel) of the GEMM function.

In the [ulmBLAS benchmarks](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/ulmBLAS) you see that about all BLAS Level 3 functions can achieve approximately the same performance.

For a more thorough reading I would suggest you the nice written paper [The Science of Programming Matrix Computations](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/sghpc/gemm) by Robert A. van de Geijn and Enrique S. Quintana-Ortí.
And you also might wanna look at [BLIS](https://github.com/flame/blis) where most of the ideas where taken and simplified for [ulmBLAS](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/ulmBLAS).

Comment: Good stuff.  Thanks for the link and the notes.

Answer (score 2):

Optimized assembly code can give you huge speed gain.

My research shows that the claims about "compilers are better" are biased, and have nothing to do with the real life. It is a myth.

Compilers are better only if you compare well written HLL program, compiled with really good compiler, with poorly written assembly program.

It is another story that there is no so many good or even decent assembly programmers. :)